# How to solve two unkowns with two equations?

Tags: functions

I am using the formula: $f(x) = b  \ln(x + c)$
and have these two equations:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccl}
31.838 &=& b  \ln(1.27 + c) \\
34.214 &=& b  \ln(13.07 + c)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

By using these equations, how do I find the value of both $b$ and $c$??

Comment: Well, quite clearly, you have $b \neq 0$, so you can divide the equations by each other and get
$$
\frac{31.838}{34.214} = \frac{ \ln (1.27 +c)  }{ \ln{(13.07 + c)}}
$$
and maybe from this you can try to solve $c$.

Comment: The numerical root for $c$ is somewhere around the same values as the left-hand sides of the equations.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get an explicit solution and you will need some numerical method for findin $c$ and from it $b$.

Using @Matti's first comment
$$\frac{31.838}{34.214} = \frac{ \log (1.27 +c)  }{ \log{(13.07 + c)}}$$ cross multiply and consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(c)=31.838\log{(13.07 + c)}-34.214\log (1.27 +c)$$
Using @Matti's second comment, use Newton method starting with $c_0=35$ and have the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & c_n \\
 0 & 35.0000 \\
 1 & 36.5500 \\
 2 & 36.6039 \\
 3 & 36.6040 
\end{array}
\right)$$ Now, use one of the equations to get $b$.